# Django SECRET_KEY called in os.environ but isn't an environment variable

Tags: django, environment-variables

I've been asked to look at a Django project where the developer has disappeared.  I cannot work out how they've set the `SECRET_KEY`.  In `settings.py` we have `SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']`

It is running on a Ubuntu 14.04.05 server.  I understand the code above to mean the `SECRET_KEY` has been set as an environment setting so in terminal I type `printenv` to see the environment settings and `SECRET_KEY` isn't there.

How might it be being set?

**EDIT**

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##
        client_body_buffer_size 10K;
        client_header_buffer_size 1k;
        client_max_body_size 8m;
        large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        client_body_timeout 12;
        client_header_timeout 12;
        keepalive_timeout 15;
        send_timeout 10;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";


        # gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied     expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_comp_level 2;
        gzip_min_length  1000;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # nginx-naxsi config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
        ##

        #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

        ##
        # nginx-passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
        ##

        #passenger_root /usr;
        #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**uwsgi_params**

```
uwsgi_param     QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
uwsgi_param     REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
uwsgi_param     CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
uwsgi_param     CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;

uwsgi_param     REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
uwsgi_param     PATH_INFO               $document_uri;
uwsgi_param     DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;
uwsgi_param     SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param     UWSGI_SCHEME            $scheme;

uwsgi_param     REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param     REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
uwsgi_param     SERVER_PORT             $server_port;
uwsgi_param     SERVER_NAME             $server_name;
```

Comment: it won't be set in the environment you're running the terminal in, presumably as your own user - it'll only be set for the process that's running the server. However you'll need to give more information about how it is being served.

Comment: It is being served by an nginx webserver

Comment: Well nginx doesn't serve apps by itself; it's just a reverse proxy, something else (eg gunicorn or uwsgi) is probably there too. You need to post the configuration file, and possibly whatever service manager configuration is responsible for starting it.

Comment: OK - I normally work with apache.  Where do I find the configuration file for nginx?

Comment: The uwsgi configuration is what you want to find. Nginx should only communicate with uwsgi over a port or socket - it should not have access to the django environment directly. How is uwsgi started? It's common to use `supervisord` for that. But there are many other options. You can use standard linux tools such as `top` to figure out the parent of uwsgi.

Comment: You could also simply use `grep` to search for a file containing `SECRET_KEY=`. It might be a shell script that is sourced by the uwsgi process.

Comment: So using top I think I'm actually running gunicorn.  How would I now find how the key is set?  I tried using grep to search for SECRET_KEY but using `grep --exclude={sys} -rnw '/' -e 'SECRET_KEY'`, but that gave loads of errors.

Answer (score 1):

There is a really simple hack I use: It worked for me, but am still testing different environments. This is how I did it. You set variables when activating your virtual environment.

Just open your bin/activate file that you source for activating the virtual environment and add something like this to the end of it:
If your virtual environment folder is, for example, "virtual", then you activate your virtual environment using this command:

```
source virtual/bin/activate
```

So, now you know where to locate your "activate" file, which is located in the virtual environment. Open it with a text editor and add the lines below  at the end of the file. NOTE: replace the characters between the quotes with your secret key.

```
export APP_SECRET_KEY="OiJjajJjZXlraGcwMDBrMndtdWJ6NDFsNWt4"
export APP_DEBUG="1"
...
```

Now everytime you activate the environment (source virtenv/bin/activate), all configuration variables will be set and available.